# Parsing nested JSON "id: value" inside "value" - inception of GET response and how to parse this

Tags: python, json, django, parsing, django-templates

There are few similar topics BUT all of them guides how to parse nested JSON if you know the number and names of ids. What i need to do is generic code.

I am creating WEB-application that uses multiple DIFFERENT GET/POST/DELETE requests.
Now i focus parsing GET requests. 
What i have now is generic template that parse not nested JSON response.

my generic ***json.html***

```
[...]
{% if response %}
    {% for id, value in response.items %}
        <p>{{ id }}: {{ value }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No IDs are available.</p>
{% endif %}
[...]
```

and its perfectly generic, works fine for all of responses i get if are not nested (id: value) for examle:

```
version: 3.4

level:

system: unix

server_time: 1560252637000

server_utc: 2
```

but when i get nested json response, this generic template is not so good. response looks like this:

```
transfers: [{'direct': 'SEND', 'type': 'MESSAGE', 'compatstate': 'T', 'ack': '', 'state': 'T', 'phase': 'X', 'phasestep': 'X', 'idf': 'NOW', 'idt': 'F1112091', 'frec': '', 'msg': 'test'}]

numberOfSelectedRecords: 2

numberOfUsedRecords: 2

numberOfRecords: 10000

offset: 0
```

adding view, maybe itll be helpful:

```
def transfers(request, host_id):
    hostname = Host.objects.get(pk=(host_id))
    response = requests.get(
        'https://{}:1769/v1/transfers?fields=aa%bb'.format(hostname),
        verify='/cert/cacerts.pem',
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
    ).json()
    context = {'response': response, 'hostname': hostname}
    return render(request, 'app/json.html', context)
```

My question is, is it possible to create generic template that would parse nested json responses? Should this be parsed within html template or somewhere inside views, before passing it to template?

Comment: You may have to right custom template tag for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the key-value pairs as follow:

```py
def iterate_over(d): 
    """ 
    This function iterate over all the key-value pairs of a dictionary
    d -- a dictionary to iterate through
    """
    if not isinstance(d, dict) and not type(d) == list:
        return

    if type(d) == list:
        for entry in d:
            iterate_over(entry)
    else:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == 'a key':   
                doSomething()
            if v == 'a value':
                doSomethingElse()
            if isinstance(v, dict) or type(v) == list:
                iterate_over(v)
    return
```

and create an  `if k == 'something'` or `if value == 'something` for each key or value in your response for which you want to perform some operation.

Comment: i'm not sure how to follow this one?

Comment: The code above just iterates through each key-value pair. If the dictionary is an instance of "dict", then get its items with ```d.items()``` and do something with its keys/values (like parse their value). Otherwise, if the "dictionary"  or the value of a key is a list, iterate over each entry of the list.

Comment: should i use this as separate view and call it inside 'transfers' view? sorry for questions but im kinda new in this

Comment: It depends on where do you process your input. If the nested response is in the variable "response" in transfers(request; host_id), then call that function there.